# Captcha response testing

Tags: php, captcha

Im trying to test a user's response from captcha input. Whenever the user inputs an incorrect response, this code works and spits out the error message but when the user inputs a correct response it doesn't return the success message. In fact, the response is empty. I've been playing with this for a couple of days and I have no idea what is going on here.. In fact, I've used this structure in other parts of my app and it has work just fine. Any ideas what could be happening?

```
if ($recaptcha_response_field !== '') {

    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "removed_this_duh...";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 
            $recaptcha_challenge_field, $recaptcha_response_field);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        $entry_display = 'Sorry, I know this sucks... 
                          but your entry was invalid, please try again.';
    } else {
        $entry_display = 'success';
    }
return $entry_display;
```

Here is the client side ajax business:

```
function(data) {

    if (data == 'success') {
        alert('success');
        $('#mask').hide();  
        $('#modal_container').hide();

    } else {
        alert(data);
        $('#captcha_error_area').empty().append(data);
        javascript:Recaptcha.reload();
    }
```

On success, here is the object I am testing:

```
Failure:     
ReCaptchaResponse Object ( [is_valid] => [error] => incorrect-captcha-sol )

Success: 
ReCaptchaResponse Object
        (
            [is_valid] => 1
            [error] => 
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the dump of your object, it looks like `is_valid` might be NULL or empty when there is an error and `error` is filled with something. In this case, I'd switch the order of your if, because `1` will evaluate to `true` and nothing will evaluate to `false`:

```
if($resp->is_valid) {
    $entry_display = 'success'; // is_vald is 1

} else {  // is_valid is empty
    $entry_display = 'Sorry, I know this sucks...but your entry was invalid, please try again.';
}
```

Comment: @Thomas What is outputted when you run `var_dump($resp->is_valid);`?

Comment: Why are you returning `$entry_display`? Is this within the context of a function or an include?

Comment: Im submitting with ajax so there is no page reload. To simplify things I am sending a string, which I test with JS - if its one string, I hide the captcha box, if its another - I display an error message.

Comment: You should be using `echo` or `print`, not `return`. `return` only works within a function, or in an included file if you include it like this `$return_value = include('thisHasAReturn.php');`. Try replacing your `return` with `echo`.

Comment: First simple answer i would see you write +

Answer (score 2):

If your code is reaching `if (!$resp->is_valid) {...` for a failure case but isn't proceeding to the `else` block under success conditions, the only possibility is that your code isn't being executed upon success... which means that:

`if ($recaptcha_response_field !== '') {`

isn't being executed. I'd wager the captcha plugin is doing something you don't expect with regards to return values. You may want to move your `include` outside of the validation block, but without seeing the rest of your code I can't comment on whether that's directly the issue.

EDIT: This didn't end up being the answer, the accepted answer is right on the money. However, my answer could be useful in similar-but-distinct circumstances so I'm leaving it up.

Comment: Hmm, I moved the required out of the if statement and nothing changed. See above, I've added the object returned from recaptchalib.php

Comment: Regardless of where the `require` is, this: `if ($recaptcha_response_field !== '') {` is resolving to false and the following block isn't being run. Therefore, `$recaptcha_response_field` DOES `== ''` which means your problem is coming from wherever that variable is set.